# Can't get USB flash drive to boot

Tags: installation, usb, boot-failure

I created a USB stick using Universal USB Installer and file `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso`. When I plug it into my notebook and **start up** it just **freezes** with the following message.

```
SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 4.06-pre1 Copyright (c) 1994-2011 H. Peter Anvin et al
```

This appears at the top of a blank screen.

Please, does anyone know how to sort this? I want to install Ubuntu onto my notebook which *doesn't have a CD/DVD drive*.