# Booting From USB Problem

Tags: boot, usb, 12.10, drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t get USB flash drive to boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153603/cant-get-usb-flash-drive-to-boot)

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu 10.12 from a usb memory stick in a first time installation, but i keep getting a message preventing me from progressing any further.

It says this.

SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD 4.06-pre1 Copyright (c) 1994-2012 H.Peter

I've reordered my bios boot priorities correctly so the usb loads before the hard drive.

My hard drive is faulty, but i am getting a new one tomorrow.

Any ideas? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the image of ubuntu was not correctly recorded to usb stick or there were errors during ubuntu iso download? I use unetbooting to make bootable usb drive and it works perfectly

Comment: Do you think this problem is down to the faulty hard drive maybe?

Comment: I am not sure but if your usb is 100% working device then the problem must be in recording .iso file to usb and there were errors  during writing it to stick or downloading the file ...i think it is suppose to boot without hard drive working just like live cd with ubuntu can.I would try to redownload iso image and rewrite it to usb (i use unetbooting)..Or try to press f8 during purple screen while booting from usb and check it for errors.At least you can make live dvd with ubuntu set to boot from dvd and see if it work. Or just be patient until tomorrow(optional).